# How to make textView wrap its multiline content exactly?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How can I make the textview wrap such text exactly ?

android:width attribute is not a solution, because the text is dynamic.

Desired behaviour

```
|Adcs  |
|adscfd|
```

Current behavour:

```
|Adcs      |
|adscfd    |
```

Hereis the code (styles of TextViews only define things like textColor, textSize, textStyle).

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title_holder"
        style="@style/TextBold.Black.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Adcs adscfd"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

The topic [wrap_content width on mutiline TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8069776/1395546) has no good answer.

Comment: Why can't you just use `android:width=WRAP_CONTENT` in XML?

Comment: remove maxWidth attribute and try

Comment: >>Why can't you just use android:width=WRAP_CONTENT
android:width attribute does not accept "wrap_content" parameter. It only accepts numeric values.

Comment: >>remove maxWidth attribute and try\n
Didn't work...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have faced this problem and didn't find the solution in internet. I did this trick by creating the new component TightTextView that remeasures the given text in case you have specified the maxWidth of the component and the width of Layout (of text) is less that the measured width of the view.

```
package com.client.android.app.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Tightly wraps the text when setting the maxWidth.
 * @author sky
 */
public class TightTextView extends TextView {
    private boolean hasMaxWidth;

    public TightTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public TightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (hasMaxWidth) {
            int specModeW = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            if (specModeW != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                Layout layout = getLayout();
                int linesCount = layout.getLineCount();
                if (linesCount > 1) {
                    float textRealMaxWidth = 0;
                    for (int n = 0; n < linesCount; ++n) {
                        textRealMaxWidth = Math.max(textRealMaxWidth, layout.getLineWidth(n));
                    }
                    int w = Math.round(textRealMaxWidth);
                    if (w < getMeasuredWidth()) {
                        super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                                heightMeasureSpec);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setMaxWidth(int maxpixels) {
        super.setMaxWidth(maxpixels);
        hasMaxWidth = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxEms(int maxems) {
        super.setMaxEms(maxems);
        hasMaxWidth = true;
    }
}
```

!!! Just did port it to older android APIs, cuz getMaxWidth() is only available since API level 16.

Comment: I'm confused about why the maxWidth stuff in here is necessary. With it, this code didn't solve the problem for me. Once I pulled it out, it worked.

Comment: I have issue cause of Math.round(). Last char of largest line is trimmed.
Replacing Math.round() with FloatMath.ceil() solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old now but I too had this problem where I wanted green text in a black box over a mapView and got around it by putting my textView in a RelativeLayout container. I then used padding to set the border size. The textView now hugs the text nicely.
My outline in eclipse looks like this.

```
RelativeLayout
    mapview
    LinearLayout
        RelativeLayout
            textView1  << this is the box I want to hug the text
        imageView1
    RelativeLayout
    etc....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?