# Why does TextView have end padding when multi line?

Tags: android, textview

If you have a TextView with `layout_width="wrap_content"` and it has to wrap to a second line to contain the text, then it will size its width to use up all of the space available (respecting margins etc). But why is there padding at the end of the view? I just told it to *wrap_content*, so it should wrap that content! This seems like a bug, this is visible in the chat UI of the stock Messenger app. (The image is from my own app though. But that extra space is definitely *not* in the 9 patch.)

Any workaround?

Update: Responders/commenters missed the point. Maybe the image I uploaded was misleading because it was styled from my app. The problem occurs with any TextView, you can see by styling the background that the view bounds will no longer be tight. I uploaded a different image. Here is the XML for the TextViews in the image:

```
        <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:text="This doesn't wrap"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:text="This wraps and look, the bounds does not fit tight against the right edge of text"
    />
```

[image]

Comment: maybe the word doesn't fit? maybe your 9patch has some inner background?

Comment: I updated my answer, it should cover your point now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first, when seeing your post, I thought that the problem was because standard Android `TextView` has some default padding defined in their base style. If one wants to remove it, one can try it something like:

```
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```

or

```
android:paddingRight="0dp"
```

As your post has been updated, I understand that your problem does not come from padding, but from word wrapping. Indeed, when there are several lines to display, Android `TextView` use the whole available space in width.

As stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913384/how-to-make-textview-wrap-its-multiline-content-exactly), there is no standard solution for this and you will need to customize your text view to fix its width after filling it.

Overriding `onMeasure` method of your `textView` like below should work (inspired from "sky" answer) :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int specModeW = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    if (specModeW != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        Layout layout = getLayout();
        int linesCount = layout.getLineCount();
        if (linesCount > 1) {
            float textRealMaxWidth = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < linesCount; ++n) {
                textRealMaxWidth = Math.max(textRealMaxWidth, layout.getLineWidth(n));
            }
            int w = (int) Math.ceil(textRealMaxWidth);
            if (w < getMeasuredWidth()) {
                super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                        heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried searching for the same question but that one didn't come up. Definitely the same problem. Sad to see that 3 years later, we still have to do a workaround for this.

Answer (score 9):

I found the selected answer to be helpful, although it didn't quite account for padding. I combined the selected answer with [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439748/why-is-wrap-content-in-multiple-line-textview-filling-parent) to come up with a view that works with padding. FYI, the other post's answer had a flaw where the view would sometimes get cut-off at the end by a few pixels.

```
public class TightTextView extends TextView {
  public TightTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public TightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public TightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int specModeW = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    if (specModeW != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
      Layout layout = getLayout();
      if (layout != null) {
        int w = (int) Math.ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout)) + getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();
        if (w < getMeasuredWidth()) {
          super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
          heightMeasureSpec);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private float getMaxLineWidth(Layout layout) {
    float max_width = 0.0f;
    int lines = layout.getLineCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      if (layout.getLineWidth(i) > max_width) {
        max_width = layout.getLineWidth(i);
      }
    }
    return max_width;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping improve the solutions for what is definitely an annoying problem.

Comment: not always working if TightTextView is located inside the ConstraintLayout, probably depends on the properties of the TightTextView element.

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced a similar problem when developing a chat-bubble view for an app, so I used the ideas from the accepted solution, and @hoffware's improvements, and re-implemented them in Kotlin.

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec.*
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
import kotlin.math.ceil

class TightTextView
@JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = android.R.attr.textViewStyle
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        val lineCount = layout.lineCount
        if (lineCount > 1 && getMode(widthMeasureSpec) != EXACTLY) {
            val textWidth = (0 until lineCount).maxOf(layout::getLineWidth)
            val padding = compoundPaddingLeft + compoundPaddingRight
            val w = ceil(textWidth).toInt() + padding

            if (w < measuredWidth) {
                val newWidthMeasureSpec = makeMeasureSpec(w, AT_MOST)
                super.onMeasure(newWidthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is because "against" doesn't fit between the word "fit" and the right edge. If you want to test this out, try changing your text to a bunch of |'s with a single space between each one.