# Larger padding only in last line of a text view

Tags: android, textview, padding, overlapping

I wonder how i can set the padding of only the last text view line larger then the padding of the other lines. (Like it is done in WhatsApp chat with the time in the chat bubble). Maybe this picture elaborates:

[image: Textview]

The padding should follow the red lines. Adding more vertical padding to move down the clock is not the solution i am looking for.

Comment: In WhatsApp the time has a fixed position, so it can be a `TextView` placed on top of the multiline text. 
You can also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800808/why-does-textview-have-end-padding-when-multi-line

Answer (score 1):

In android you can't apply padding for specific line into TextView

You have 2 solution :

1- Merge both text in one text Html

2- Align both textview end and bottom and add 8 spaces in the end of message

[example worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ5mU.png)