# Minimise width of a text view for a given maximum width in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am building a chat UI.

I want a TextView which:

1. Is exactly 16dp from the left of the layout
2. Is at least 150dp from the right of the layout
3. Has the minimum number of lines that satisfy the above constraints yet still shows all text
4. Has the minimum width possible for the amount of lines, while still showing all the text

The layout is currently failing on 4).

Here is my current layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        android:text="This is a message that should wrap tightly" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The below is what the layout looks like.

[image]

I want to get rid of the extra space to the right of the TextView, as shown by the red arrow. This is important as I plan to put a bubble UI around the TextView and it would look odd if it has this extra space.

Comment: did u tried changing the `breakStrategy` ?

Comment: Yes, the TextView is still the same width (wider than it needs to be)

Comment: i think it's a standard behaviour when having multi line text wraped in ur textView. Have a look  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40800911/14734532

Comment: So, `android:breakStrategy="simple"` doesn't work for you? What Android version are you testing and which version of _ConstraintLayout_?

Comment: I'm testing SDK version 32. When I set it to breakStrategy="simple", the TextView stays the same width, but the top line is roughly the width of the view.

Comment: I see. It looks like DrHowdyDoo has the right idea. It looks like you will have to address the measurement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up having to implement a custom class to solve this:

```
class LineBreakTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val layout: Layout? = layout
        if (layout != null) {
            val width = (Math.ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout).toDouble()).toInt() + compoundPaddingLeft + compoundPaddingRight)
            val height = measuredHeight
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
        }
    }

    private fun getMaxLineWidth(layout: Layout): Float {
        var maxWidth = 0.0f
        val lines: Int = layout.lineCount
        for (i in 0 until lines) {
            if (layout.getLineWidth(i) > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = layout.getLineWidth(i)
            }
        }
        return maxWidth
    }
}
```